# R Convert Chr String to Minutes & Seconds

Tags: r

I have a data set with times as strings representing minutes and seconds in the format mm:ss.s. It currently looks like:

```
"00:14.3"
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to times so that I can work with the data (plot etc)?

I have tried the Chron package, but this seems to require the string to be hh:mm:ss unless I've misunderstood

Comment: With chron one can try this `times(paste0("00:", "00:14.3"), format = "h:m:s")`, but the fractional seconds are rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [strptime with a custom format string](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) like so:

```
> strptime("00:14.3", format="%M:%OS")
[1] "2016-08-24 00:00:14 PDT"
```

Note that this will create a full datetime object using your current date and timezone. To see that the fractional second has been preserved, make sure your options(digits.secs) is set like this:

```
> options(digits.secs=2)
> strptime("00:14.3", format="%M:%OS")
[1] "2016-08-24 00:00:14.30 PDT"
```

You can adjust the date and timezone manually or with the strptime options. Depending on how you're using this, you can always format that back out into a string (reproduced here to prove no information was lost in the conversion):

```
> strftime(t, format="%M:%OS")
[1] "00:14.30"
```

Comment: this works great, thank you. Is there a way to change the date, to avoid it showing as today?

Comment: R objects are funny - in my answer I suggested creating posix datetimes which always have a date attribute (which you can certainly change if you want). Depending on what you're trying to do you can absolutely change the date, or you could use the chron::times function to produce formatted doubles like this: `times(paste0("00:", "01:20.03"))`

Comment: Sorry for multiple comments - just realized this but you might get data loss using the times function, the chron package doesn't seem to support fractions of seconds.